# System.Windows.Media.Brush XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization, brush

In my `WPF` application I have a `Project` class which has a HashSet of `Layout`s, each Layout has a HashSet of special special objects. What I need to do is to serialize "Project" and it was working perfectly until I found out I need to add `Brush` to one of the types of the special objects. So now it doesn't work, because Brush is not serializable. Here is how I serialize the Project:

```
public static void WriteXML(LCTProject project)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(LCTProject));
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(project.Path);
        writer.Serialize(file, project);
        file.Close();
    }

    public static LCTProject ReadXML(string path)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(LCTProject));
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        LCTProject project = new LCTProject();
        project = (LCTProject)reader.Deserialize(file);
        return project;
    }
```

How can I make Project serializable if deep down inside it has a `Brush`? Maybe there is a function I can add? I found this one: [How can i serialize xaml "Brush"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488476/how-can-i-serialize-xaml-brush) but unfortunately, it doesn't help me.

Comment: Why does it not help you?

Comment: How can I use it so that when I serialize Project it will serialize the Brush when needed? @L.B

Comment: So you haven't tried it...

Comment: I tried to adjust it to my code, but it didn't help. Maybe I didn't put it in the right place, or i don't know what..

Comment: Have you ever encountered my problem? @L.B

Comment: Brush can't be serialized easily. Could you perhaps just have a `Color` instead of `Brush`?

Comment: Yes, I though about ways around it, just wanted to know if there is a way do to it straight away. So the answer is that it is too complicated. Nevermind, Thank you @Clemens